# What is the time complexity of the following Power Of Two code?

Tags: c#, time, time-complexity

I would like to know the time complexity of the following code. If it is not constant time, what is a better solution?

```
static bool powerOfTwo(double number)
{
    double log = Math.Log(number, 2); 
    double pow = Math.Pow(2, Math.Round(log));
    return pow == number;
}
```

Comment: It is constant time. O(1).

Comment: yes it's constant time `O(k)` where k is constant

Answer (score 1):

It's constant time, but it's not the fastest constant time solution. If we're happy with incorrect answers on *really* small `double`s (i.e subnormals)

```
long bits = BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(number);
return (bits & 0xfffffffffffffL == 0L) && number != 0.0;
```

We simply pull out the mantissa and check that it's zero (well, actually 1, because there's an implicit 1 on all normal doubles). If this is true, the number must be a power of two, or 0. If you want this to work for subnormal numbers it's a bit more work.